# UITextView not displaying keyboard inside CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I am experiencing some difficulty in getting a UITextView to display a keyboard when tapped by the User. I am testing my app on a live device and not the simulator, so it is not the common "keyboard in simulator" issue a lot of developers experience.

I believe it might have something to do with the structure of the app.

I have a `TableViewController` with a cell that contains a `CollectionViewController`, and the `UITextView` is inside a `CollectionViewCell`.

I had this working in the past, but my fix does not appear to be working anymore. (I'm updating this app for the 1st time in 4 years), So I have stripped out all the code relating to other components in the cell and am now working with just this code (In order of "what should be called first):

***`TableViewCell` for statuses:***

This bit of code is inside `tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath)`

```
case 5:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "status") as! StatusTableViewCell
            cell.collectionView.event = self.event
            cell.collectionView.doLoad()
            cell.collectionView.rootView = self
            return cell
```

***StatusTableViewCell***

This contains the CollectionView which should display a list of "Statuses" (imagine if Facebook was horizontal)

class StatusTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
var collectionView: StatusView

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    collectionView = StatusView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    doSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


func doSetup(){
    
    //backgroundColor = .black
    addSubview(collectionView)
    
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": collectionView]))
    
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": collectionView])) 
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

***StatusView***

This is the bit of code that calls the `NewStatusViewCell`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("=====INDEX===== ", indexPath.row - 1)
    print("number of statuses: ", statuses.count)
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        print("creating newStatus")
        let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NewStatusCell", for: indexPath) as! NewStatusViewCell
        
       // cell.event = self.event
        
        return cell
}
```

***NewStatusViewCell***

This should always be called as the very first cell, and let's users post new statuses

```
class NewStatusViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

let status = UITextView()
var event: Event? = nil
let placeholder = UILabel(frame: .zero)
let post = UIButton(type: .custom)

let tutorialView = UIView(frame: .zero)

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    backgroundColor = .white
    
    status.frame = .zero
    
    status.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(status)
    status.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    status.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    status.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
    status.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    
    status.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    status.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    status.isEditable = true
}
```

The original code included using this class as a delegate, but I have commented out all the relevant delegate code to try to get the textView to run with only apple's code, however before I did this I added a `print()` statement to the `textViewShouldBeginEditing()` function. This statement never appeared in my logs indicating it was never called

I know I've just layed out ALOT of code, but if anyone can see where I've gone wrong I would really appreciate any help you can offer.

As always please don't hesitate to ask for more information.

Thanks :)

***EDIT***

This is what the app looks like just now, the white box underneath "invitees" is the `CollectionViewCell` and the box inside that is the `UITextView`

[image: The current layout of the app]

Comment: The problem is probably this line in your `NewStatusViewCell` class:  `addSubview(status)` -- it should be `contentView.addSubview(status)`

Comment: @DonMag I tried adding `contentView` to my code but nothing changed

Comment: is this iOS 14 compiled with xcode 12?

Comment: Yeh, iOS 14 and Xcode 12

Comment: @Andy - use `Debug View Hierarchy` to see if you've somehow ended up with another view on top of the textView.

Comment: @DonMag good call, there is a `UITableViewCellContentView` in front of the `UITextView`

Comment: @Andy - sorry... guess my first comment should have included "and check you're not doing the same thing in the table cell".

Comment: @DonMag you are correct, inside `StatusTableViewCell.doSetup()` I had `addSubView` for adding the collectionView to the cell. If you wanna post your answer I'll accept it for you :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very common cause is adding subViews to the cell:

```
addSubview(status)
```

instead of to the cell's content view:

```
contentView.addSubview(status)
```

This applies to both `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell`

Worth noting: for auto-layout, subViews should **also** be constrained to the `contentView` and not to the cell itself.